# Removing the number in a category slug

Tags: categories, slug

I have a category that ends with -2, and there's no way I can change it back to the plain word. I know there are problems with numeric slugs, but this is just a word. I also know that a common answer is to look in the trash, but there's no trash for categories as far as I'm aware

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a tag with the same slug. You can't have any taxonomies with duplicate slugs. Either delete that other taxonomy, rename/change its slug, or change/rename this category.

EDIT

Ok, it turns out you can do this, if you don't mind programming the fix or directly executing the SQL or messing with PHPMyAdmin. What you need to do is add a new row in `wp_term_taxonomy` that uses the term with the slug you want to use as the `term_id` and the new taxonomy (category in this case) as the `taxonomy`. This is necessary because, if the slug already exists, WP creates a new term rather than using the same term with a different term_taxonomy relationship.

Comment: Great, I didn't realize tags and categories shared the same space

Comment: Huh? All categories at my blog are duplicated as tags with exactly same name and slug. I need to get rid of tags some time, but works just fine.

Comment: @Rarst That's actually not possible. The slug field in the terms table of the database requires unique information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_terms I don't know the specifics of your site, but my guess is that your site is using some term_taxonomy magic to pull that one off.

Comment: Ok, looked into it. It sounds like Rarst used the category/tag converter. That uses the established set of terms (from either categories or tags) and doesn't recreate the term, only creates a new term_taxonomy and duplicates the term_relationships that exist. So Rarst, your terms aren't duplicated, they have two term_relationships.

Comment: Ehm, never converted anything, never knew there even was a restriction on names/slugs... http://www.rarst.net/category/software/ http://www.rarst.net/tag/software/ My only guess it wasn't required in earlier versions and my structure was grandfathered, it's >2 years old.

Comment: Yeah, looks like 2.3 used wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy, and wp_term_relationships to replace wp_categories, post2cat, and link2cat tables. I'm not sure how those worked, but I'm guessing the upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3 would have done that for you.

Comment: **DISCLAIMER for later readers:** If you want to hack the DB [for a reason like »I don't like the way this slug looks like«](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45101/i-use-same-slug-name-for-category-and-page), then you're running straight into a mine field. Make sure that you really, really(!) know what you're doing and that you have a damn good reason to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there you used such category name before as subcategory or category and then deleted it. When you created second time category with such name- it got -2.

I had a similar problem. Just removed a new category with -2 slug, then created category in subcategory directory where I deleted it. Then just changed parent- made it parent category.

Comment: As John explained, it can be any term from any post object taxonomy.