# I use same slug name for category and page

Tags: categories, pages, slug, seo

I added one slug and page with the same name and they worked fine, but when creating a second WP forced me to rename the page (being created after the category) with an additional "-2" how to clear the additional "-2".

if i delete the category and create new category in same name then it display as "-3"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have duplicate slugs or taxonomies, to remove the number you will need to delete them.

There is a database hack to have duplicate terms but it's probably not a great idea, [Removing the number in a category slug](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/removing-the-number-in-a-category-slug)

Comment: +1 Maybe you want to write "but it's probably not a great idea" bold :)

Comment: I don't know what hack you're talking about but I have a page and a post with the same slug. It can cause problems, but there is no warning ahead of time.

Comment: This was fixed in a more recent version of WordPress, maybe yours is outdated or it's possible you made those posts when WordPress allowed it. Also some plugins like WPML allow this.